# fetching data from database and set it on edittext

Tags: android, database, android-edittext

I am doing a registration page for my application.For this I need to insert the registration details in to sqlite DB.Once the registration is done,the edittext fields should display those details fetching it from database and the submit button and text fields should be disabled to stop from a second time registration.Can anyone suggest the suitable way?

Comment: Have u tried any code........

Comment: yes.I used cursor.But it didnt work

Comment: Once registration is done u will be on the same page?

Comment: no its navigating to another page where i can view some details provided in the registration page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check code for database in the following link  [Android SQLite](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

You have to store the value in an arraylist and which is retrieved from database and set the value to the edit text as

```
// myarraylist is the arraylist which contains 
// the data retrieved from database
editText.setText(myarraylist.get(0));
```

After the data is retrieved, you have to check the condition whether `editText.getText().toString()` length is greater then zero you should not allow them to edit the text in `editText` by using following

```
  editText.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write/read into database easily: read this for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db
and this
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sqlite/

To get data from edit text, you can do this: `myEditText.getText().toString()`